# Понятие инварианта в многопоточном программировании

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Изучаю многопоточное программирование по книге "С++ Параллельное программирование" за Авторством Энтони Уильямса и он вводит такие понятие как "Инвариантность" и ссылается на него при объяснении раздельной работы с данными. Я не могу понять что значит этот термин. Объясните пожалуйста мне его на пальцах.

Comment: Свойство какого либо объекта не изменяться при изменении условий, в которых он существует

Comment: Ну, если на пальцах: представьте, что нужно снять отпечатки пальцев с вашей руки. Можно сделать это последовательно, палец за пальцем. А можно распараллелить: каждый палец запихнуть отдельно в некий датчик. Так вот после этой операции и пальцы, и кисть руки, должны остаться целыми.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, ха_ха, пример из области криминала, но хороший пример...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, скорее тогда уж оба метода должны дать одинаковые результаты.... а что с кистью будет ­— дело десятое... хотя тут контекст употребления не помешал бы...